# How can all information be localized if local realism is dead?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-interpretations

I'm confused about whether quantum mechanics is local or not.

The authors of a [recent, much publicized](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v526/n7575/full/nature15759.html) experiment argue that their results "imply statistically significant rejection of the local-realist null hypothesis" and the editors of *Nature* even go so far as to title the [accompanying news piece](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v526/n7575/full/nature15631.html): **"Death by experiment for local realism"**.

But [David Deutsch](http://www.daviddeutsch.org.uk), in [his description](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.7439) of Constructor Theory says that it requires "Einstein’s principle of locality" that "for any two spatially separated physical systems $S_1$ and $S_2$, the real factual situation of the system $S_2$ is independent of what is done with the system $S_1$", in support of which he cites [a paper of his](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223) describing "local formulations of quantum theory" which in turn relies on an [earlier paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007) in which he claims that
 **"All information in quantum systems is, notwithstanding Bell's theorem, localized**."

I'm a beginner at this, so maybe I'm missing some terminological or definitional sleight of hand; but on the face of it, these two statements can't both be true, can they? All information can't be localized, *and* local realism can't be dead, can it?

Comment: Unsatisfying "answer" (like with all such questions about "interpretations"): It depends on what, exactly, you mean by "local". And probably on which interpretation you adhere to.

Comment: "Local realism" is a philosophical term that has no meaning in physics. If the philosophy department cares about it... that's OK. Physics was done with all of this in the late 1920s, when the structural aspects of the theory were essentially finished, and nothing new has been learned by these experiments, since. Every new experiment that tries to "untangle" philosophical terms basically confirms that what we knew then is all there is to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Paradox**

The thing confusing you is the [apparent paradox between](http://algorithmicassertions.com/quantum/2015/10/11/Bell-Tests-vs-No-Communication.html) the [No Communication Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem) and [Bell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem).

The No Communication Theorem says that there's no way to transfer information via separated quantum systems (even if they start off entangled). Bell's Theorem says that correlations displayed by quantum systems are classically non-local. Classically emulating a distributed quantum mechanical system would require communication.

It seems like communication is both forbidden and required.

**Solution**

The resolution to the paradox is that the theorems are talking about different kinds of communication.

Bell's Theorem is about interactions ***inside* the mathematical model**. It says a classical simulation can't factor the state and still get the correct predictions. The No Communication Theorem is about layering useful communication ***on top of* the mathematical model**. It says that entities inside a classical simulation of the quantum system can't exploit the hidden communication to do any useful communication. They can see some weird non-local correlations, but they can't use those correlations to communicate.

Or, [as Scott Aaronson puts it](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2464):

> quantum mechanics exhibits what one might not have realized beforehand was even a logical possibility: it doesn’t allow communication faster than light, but simulating the predictions of quantum mechanics in a classical universe would require faster-than-light communication.

What David Deutsh means when he says that "the real factual situation of the system $S_2$ is independent of what is done with the system $S_1$" is that $S_2$'s [marginal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) state (i.e. its local state uninformed by $S_1$, i.e. the density matrix you get when you trace out $S_1$ because you don't know what's happening there) is not affected by operations at $S_1$. This is a concrete consequence of the no-communication theorem: if there wasn't some localized description of $S_2$ that was independent of operations on $S_1$ and predicted all possible uninformed-by-$S_1$ measurement-of-$S_2$ probabilities, we would be able to communicate into $S_2$ by touching $S_1$.

**Example**

Here is a quantum logic circuit, showing the [marginal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) [state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) of the top wire's qubit in green (as a point on the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere)) as various operations are applied:

[image: EPR circuit with states showing]

The top qubit's state starts at -Z (the OFF state). Then the Hadamard operation rotates it to -X (the On + Off state). Then the controlled-not operation entangles it with the bottom qubit, putting the system as a whole into a Bell state (On On + Off Off). This forces the top qubit's marginal state (i.e. what you get when ignoring the bottom qubit) to the maximally mixed state at 0.

Finally, a few operations happen to the bottom qubit, but they don't affect the top qubit's marginal state. However, when we look at the top qubit's state conditioned on the bottom qubit's measurement result (shown in red), we see that there is strong correlation.

Operations on the bottom qubit don't affect the top qubit's marginal state. That's the no communication theorem at work. Yet there's lots of correlation between the measurement result and the state of the top qubit (and there would be different strong correlations for different measurements). Bell's theorem is a consequence.

Comment: Can you make this a bit more beginner-accesable (and draw some pictures; ideally as circuits)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I added an example.

Comment: Thanks! Could you say a bit more about "marginal state"?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius It's what you get when you try to describe a subset of a system without talking about the whole system. See the [wikipedia article on marginal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) and the [wikipedia article on density matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) (a nice representation for quantum marginal states).

Comment: Still pondering this excellent answer. There a few things I'm stumbling over, notably that, as beginner, the Bloch Sphere representations in the diagram are showing something different than I'm familiar with. I'm at the point of just thinking of the BS as a way of representing the state of a cubit; but here they're being used to represent a kind of PMF (the marginal PMF of the cubit's state) such states (actually something more like the expected value of that PMF). Is that about right?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yeah, that's about right. Points on the surface of the Bloch sphere correspond to nice pure states. Points inside the Bloch sphere correspond to mixed states, where there's uncertainty about which pure state the qubit is in. That uncertainty can be due to entanglement with other unconsidered qubits or due to a lack of knowledge (e.g. a measurement was performed but you don't have the result to condition on).

Comment: And, critically, the mixed state version of a BS is really a kind of expected value (the pure state is too, I suppose, but a degenerate one, of a random variable with a single certain outcome). Right?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Basically.

Comment: (Some questions you might be able to help with: (1) recommendations for [drawing quantum diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298296/7844) — circuits and Bloch Spheres; [how the "mod 2" dot product](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/242321/2540) gets introduced into Simon's algorithm: see my last comment on the — confused — answer, which I think is the answer I'm looking for.)

Comment: This is a perfectly correct answer but a little bit too nice. That simply isn't what Duetsch meant -- he really, actually meant that QM is wrong and physics is local and deterministic. He's been publishing lots of papers/rants in the past decade about this and the "Constructor Theory" mentioned by the OP is his attempt to refute QM and simultaneously explain the origin of life and formulate a theory of everything. The answer should have pointed out explicitly that taking this kind of stuff seriously is a very bad idea.