# How is the range of $x\cdot s$ in Simon's algorithm restricted to $\{0,1\}$?

Tags: quantum-information, linear-algebra, discrete

The final critical step of [Simon's algorithm](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/CPSC519/LectureNotes/06.pdf) (before setting up a simpler system of equations to solve) involves taking advantage of the fact that

$$x\cdot s \in\{0,1 \}$$

but for $x,s \in \{0,1\}^n$ isn't it the case that $x\cdot s  \in \{0,1\}^n$?

The dot product is introduced into the algorithm by application of an n-bit Hadamard transform of the form

$$H^{\otimes n}\left|x\right>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n}}}\sum_{y\in\mathbb{Z}_{2^{n}}}(-1)^{x\cdot y}\left|y\right>$$

which, though it takes advantage of he fact the the exponents of $-1$ are equivalent modulo 2, does not (seem) to require that the dot product is defined as being modulo 2.

How is the range of the dot product $x\cdot s$ in Simon's algorithm restricted to $\{0,1\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of Simon's algorithm (as well as comparable algorithms), 
$x\cdot y$ is defined as the scalar product of the $\mathbb Z_2$-vectorspaces $\mathbb Z_2^N$, i.e., as a map 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb Z_2^N\times \mathbb Z_2^N&\rightarrow Z_2
\\
x\cdot y&\mapsto x_1y_1 + x_2y_2+\dots + x_Ny_N\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $x=x_1x_2\cdots x_N$ (and the same for $y$), and the addition is over $\mathbb Z_2$ (the field underlying the vector space). The resulting number is thus naturally in $\mathbb Z_2=\{0,1\}$.

In fact, if you read the lecture just preceding the one you link ([Lecture 5](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/CPSC519/LectureNotes/05.pdf)), you will read there

> We also use the shorthand
>   $$
> x\cdot y =\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i\pmod 2
> $$

Comment: Got it! Shouldn't that be either $x\cdot y \equiv\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i\pmod 2$ or $x\cdot y = (\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i)\bmod 2$